# dot missing after the number of section when using llncs.cls

Tags: numbering

I want to use `llncs.cls` to make a book. But after I put

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem1}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem1]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[theorem1]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem1]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem1]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{defi}[theorem1]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[theorem1]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exa}[theorem1]{Example}
```

in the head, the dots in the theorem numbers  miss. For example, in section 2,
the first theorem should be Theorem 2.1, but I got Theorem 21. How to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: The class discourages adding as prefix another counter such as the one for sections. Why do you want to change this if anyways Springer will discard the change?

Answer (score 2):

The `llncs` class discourages adding as prefix another counter such as the one for sections. If you change this, most probably Springer will discard the change.

That being said, you can achieve what you want using

```
\numberwithin{theorem1}{section}
```

*after* the definition of `theorem1`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem1}{Theorem}[section]
\numberwithin{theorem1}{section}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem1]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[theorem1]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem1]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem1]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{defi}[theorem1]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[theorem1]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exa}[theorem1]{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\begin{theorem1}
Test theorem
\end{theorem1}

\begin{pro}
Test proposition
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Also, notice that the class handles theorem-like structures in its own way through the `\spnewtheorem`, so you could better use

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\spnewtheorem{theorem1}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\counterwithin{theorem1}{section}
\spnewtheorem{lem}[theorem1]{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{thm}[theorem1]{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{pro}[theorem1]{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{cor}[theorem1]{Corollary}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{defi}[theorem1]{Definition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{rem}[theorem1]{Remark}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{exa}[theorem1]{Example}{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\begin{theorem1}
Test theorem
\end{theorem1}

\begin{pro}
Test proposition
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

to be fully compliant with `llncs` style:

[image]

Notice, in particular, the final dot after the counter (not used when using `amsmath` and `\newtheorem`)